# Zoom an image with respect to a given image

Tags: image-processing

I posted this question in stack overflow, but I think it is more appropriate here:

I have a reference image - 'image_01.png' of size 200x200 and resolution 72 px/in.

I have another image 'image_02.png' (with the same size and resolution) with several levels of zoom, of which, one is close to 'image_01.png', in the sense that the objects in that image are of "similar" size. They are **NOT** the same images, btw.

Here is an example with three levels of zoom, and clearly zoom_02 is "closer" to image_01 than zoom_01 and zoom_02. My question is, what mathematical metric (ratio, or any measure) do we choose to determine what zoom is appropriate to ensure such similarity? Let's say I even have a screen ruler to measure the distance in the images, in pixels.

[image: image_02_zoom_03] zoom_03 [image: image_02_zoom_01] zoom_01

[image: image_02_zoom_02] zoom_02 [image: image_01] image_01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want the image size and resolution to remain constant, the term `optical magnification` seems apt there.

You could then say

> Please use 20x **optical magnification** to identify *said* feature.

Please be careful that the term `magnification` is different from `zoom`.

Two different cameras with the same 5x `optical zoom` might produce images with different `optical magnification` depending on their optics.

`Zoom` refers to the ratio of the max to min focal length of your camera, whereas, 
`Magnification` refers to the ratio of `projection size` to the `real subject size`.

Given a particular magnification, you could use your camera focal lengths and apertures to come up with at zoom metric for that particular camera to produce the desired results.

See [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/54296) for a better explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Yes, I found out there was a software that used the optical magnification to output the area. Your explanation is helpful.